# Rounding Numbers that fall within variable number of ranges in Python

Tags: python, list, replace, compression, range

I have an input list of numbers:

```
lst = [3.253, -11.348, 6.576, 2.145, -11.559, 7.733, 5.825]
```

I am trying to think of a way to replace each number in a list with a given number if it falls into a range. I want to create multiple ranges based on min and max of input list and a input number that will control how many ranges there is.
Example, if i said i want 3 ranges equally divided between min and max.

```
numRanges = 3
lstMin = min(lst)
lstMax = max(lst)
step = (lstMax - lstMin) / numRanges

range1 = range(lstMin, lstMin + step)
range2 = range(range1 + step)
range3 = range(range2 + step)
```

Right away here, is there a way to make the number of ranges be driven by the numRanges variable? 
Later i want to take the input list and for example if:

```
for i in lst:
    if i in range1:
        finalLst.append(1) #1 comes from range1 and will be growing if more ranges
    elif i in range2:
        finalLst.append(2) #2 comes from range2 and will be growing if more ranges
    else i in range3:
        finalLst.append(3) #3 comes from range2 and will be growing if more ranges
```

The way i see this now it is all "manual" and I am not sure how to make it a little more flexible where i can just specify how many ranges and a list of numbers and let the code do the rest. Thank you for help in advance.

```
finalLst = [3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do with basic mathematical operations in a list comprehension:

```
numRanges = 3
lstMin = min(lst)
lstMax = max(lst) + 1e-12 # small value added to avoid floating point rounding issues
step = (lstMax - lstMin) / numRanges

range_numbers = [int((x-lstMin) / step) for x in lst]
```

This will give an integer for each value in the original list, with `0` indicating that the value falls in the first range, `1` being the second, and so on. It's almost the same as your code, but the numbers start at `0` rather than `1` (you could stick a `+ 1` in the calculation if you really want 1-indexing).

The small value I've added to `lstMax` is there for two reasons. The first is to make sure that floating point rounding issues don't make the largest value in the list yield `numRange` as its range index rather than `numRange-1` (indicating the `numRange`th range). The other reason is to avoid a division by zero error if the list only contains a single value (possibly repeated multiple times) such that `min(lst)` and `max(lst)` return the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a very nice tool for doing exactly this kind of work called [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html). Lets say your range list is defined as such:

```
ranges = [-15, -10, -5, 5, 10, 15]
```

For your input list, you simply call bisect, like so:

```
lst = [3.253, -11.348, 6.576, 2.145, -11.559, 7.733, 5.825]
results = [ranges[bisect(ranges, element)] for element in lst]
```

Which results in

```
>>>[5, -10, 10, 5, -10, 10, 10]
```

You can then extend this to any arbitrary list of ranges using `ranges = range(start,stop,step)` in python 2.7 or `ranges = list(range(start,stop,step))` in python 3.X

**Update**

Reread your question, and this is probably closer to what you're looking for (still using bisect):

```
from numpy import linspace
from bisect import bisect_left

def find_range(numbers, segments):
    mx = max(numbers)
    mn = mn(numbers)
    ranges = linspace(mn, mx, segments)
    return [bisect_left(ranges, element)+1 for element in numbers]

>>> find_range(lst, 3)
[3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3]
```